# "Failed to create shortcut" error during installation

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I tried to install Qgis and I can't start Qgis at the end of the installation because I don't have any shortcut.
In the postinstall.log is written "failed to create shortcut...

What should I do please ?

Here is the postinstall report:

```
Impossible de trouver C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\preremove-conf.bat
OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads
OSGEO4W_ROOT_MSYS=/C/Users/viret-m/Downloads
OSGEO4W_STARTMENU=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14
OSGEO4W_DESKTOP=C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14
Running postinstall gdal-python.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\make-bat-for-py.bat"

    Generating .bat files for all .py files in C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin

Running postinstall grass.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set ICON=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set BATCH=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\grass72.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\grass72.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads"\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\etc\fontcap 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14\GRASS GIS 7.2.0.lnk"       "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\grass72.bat"  "-gui" \ "Launch GRASS GIS 7.2.0" 1 "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico"  

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.


Failed to create the shortcut.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Desktop\GRASS GIS 7.2.0.lnk" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\grass72.bat"  "-gui" \ "Launch GRASS GIS 7.2.0" 1 "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico"  

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.


Failed to create the shortcut.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem run g.mkfontcap outside a GRASS session during 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem an OSGeo4W installation for updating paths to fonts 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem set gisbase 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set GISBASE=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem set path to freetype dll and its dependencies 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set FREETYPEBASE=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin;C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\msys\bin;C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\lib 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem set dependencies to path 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set PATH=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin;C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\msys\bin;C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\lib;C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin;C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Windows\CCM 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem GISRC must be set 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set GISRC=dummy 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem run g.mkfontcap outside a GRASS session 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\bin\g.mkfontcap.exe" -o 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>del "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\grass72.bat.tmpl 
Running postinstall liblas.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin/liblas.bat 
Running postinstall msvcrt2008.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>for %f in ("C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp") do call set TEMPDRIVE=%~df 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call set TEMPDRIVE=C: 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>cd "C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp" 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\vcredist_2008_x86.exe" /q 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>if errorlevel 3010 echo1>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\reboot" 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>del "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\vcredist_2008_x86.exe" 
Running postinstall msvcrt2010.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>for %f in ("C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp") do call set TEMPDRIVE=%~df 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call set TEMPDRIVE=C: 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>cd "C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp" 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\vcredist_2010_x86.exe" /q 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>if errorlevel 3010 echo1>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\reboot" 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>del "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\vcredist_2010_x86.exe" 
Running postinstall msvcrt2013.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>for %f in ("C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp") do call set TEMPDRIVE=%~df 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call set TEMPDRIVE=C: 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>cd "C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp" 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\vcredist_2013_x86.exe" /q 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>if errorlevel 3010 echo1>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\reboot" 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>del "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\vcredist_2013_x86.exe" 
Running postinstall msvcrt2015.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>for %f in ("C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp") do call set TEMPDRIVE=%~df 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call set TEMPDRIVE=C: 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>cd "C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp" 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\vcredist_2015_x86.exe" /q 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>if errorlevel 3010 echo1>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\reboot" 

C:\Users\viret-m\AppData\Local\Temp>del "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\vcredist_2015_x86.exe" 
Running postinstall openssl.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>dllupdate -oite -copy -reboot "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\libeay32.dll" 
C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\libeay32.dll: Version=1.0.2.10
C:\Windows\system32\libeay32.dll: Version=0.0.0.0
Target does not exist, no action.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>dllupdate -oite -copy -reboot "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\ssleay32.dll" 
C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\ssleay32.dll: Version=1.0.2.10
C:\Windows\system32\ssleay32.dll: Version=0.0.0.0
Target does not exist, no action.
Running postinstall pyqt4.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin\pyuic4.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\Users\\viret-m\\Downloads 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyqtconfig.py 
Running postinstall python.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\make-bat-for-py.bat" 

    Generating .bat files for all .py files in C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin

Running postinstall qgis-ltr-common.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\o4w_env.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>REM Make parent of this script location our current directory, 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>REM converting UNC path to drive letter if needed 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>pushd C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\ 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin>cd .. 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>REM set OSGEO4W_ROOT to short path version 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>for %i in ("C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads") do set OSGEO4W_ROOT=%~fsi 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>REM start with clean path 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set path=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>for %f in ("C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\*.bat") do call "%f" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\gdal.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>SET GDAL_DATA=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\share\gdal 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>SET GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\gdalplugins 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\libgeotiff.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>SET GEOTIFF_CSV=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\share\epsg_csv 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\liblas.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>SET GDAL_DATA=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\share\gdal 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\msvcrt.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem This is just a dummy to make sure the for loop in ..\..\osgeo4w.bat  

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>rem always has some files to process. 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\proj.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>SET PROJ_LIB=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\share\proj 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\python.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>SET PYTHONHOME=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\Python27 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>SET PATH=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\Python27\Scripts 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\qt4.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qt4\plugins 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set QT_RASTER_CLIP_LIMIT=4096 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>call "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\etc\ini\rbatchfiles.bat" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\R\" C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\rbatchfiles\R path 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>popd

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>path C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\bin 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Users/viret-m/Downloads/apps/qgis-ltr 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>"C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\crssync"
Running postinstall qgis-ltr-grass-plugin7.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis-ltr-grass7.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis-ltr-browser-grass7.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" == "" set OSGEO4W_DESKTOP=~$folder.common_desktop$ 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" 
AccŠs refus‚.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" "QGIS Desktop 2.14.14 with GRASS 7.2.0" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr-grass7.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" "QGIS Browser 2.14.14 with GRASS 7.2.0" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr-browser-grass7.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\browser.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" 
AccŠs refus‚.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" "QGIS Desktop 2.14.14 with GRASS 7.2.0" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr-grass7.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" "QGIS Browser 2.14.14 with GRASS 7.2.0" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr-browser-grass7.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\browser.ico" 
Running postinstall qgis-ltr.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis-ltr.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis-ltr-browser.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis-ltr-designer.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin\python-qgis-ltr.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>REM get short path without blanks 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>for %i in ("C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads") do set O4W_ROOT=%~fsi 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set O4W_ROOT=C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" == "" set OSGEO4W_DESKTOP=~$folder.common_desktop$ 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" 
AccŠs refus‚.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" "QGIS Desktop 2.14.14" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" "QGIS Browser 2.14.14" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr-browser.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\browser.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" "Qt Designer with QGIS 2.14.14 custom widgets" "exec hide """C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr-designer.bat"" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" 
AccŠs refus‚.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" "QGIS Desktop 2.14.14" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" "QGIS Browser 2.14.14" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr-browser.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\browser.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" "Qt Designer with QGIS 2.14.14 custom widgets" "exec hide C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\qgis-ltr-designer.bat" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\Users\\viret-m\\Downloads 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgis.reg" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>nircmd elevate "C:\Windows\regedit" /s "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgis.reg" 
Running postinstall qt4-devel.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\Users\\viret-m\\Downloads 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t "C:\\Users\\viret-m\\Downloads"\apps\Qt4\mkspecs\default\qmake.conf 
Running postinstall qt4-libs.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:/Users/viret-m/Downloads 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t "C:/Users/viret-m/Downloads"\bin\qt.conf 
Running postinstall saga-ltr.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" == "" set OSGEO4W_DESKTOP=C:\ProgramData\Desktop 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" 
AccŠs refus‚.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" "SAGA GIS (2.3.1)" "exec hide "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\saga-ltr_gui.bat""" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\saga-ltr\saga_gui.exe" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" 
AccŠs refus‚.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" "SAGA GIS (2.3.1)" "exec hide "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\saga-ltr_gui.bat""" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\apps\saga-ltr\saga_gui.exe" 
Running postinstall setup.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>nircmd shortcut "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" "Setup" "exec hide ~qC:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\bin\setup.bat~q -R ~qC:\Users\viret-m\Downloads~q" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\OSGeo4W.ico" 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin/setup.bat 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t bin/setup-test.bat 
Running postinstall shell.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14" 
AccŠs refus‚.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS 2.14\OSGeo4W.lnk" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\OSGeo4W.bat" " " \ "OSGeo for Windows command shell" 1 "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\OSGeo4W.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.


Failed to create the shortcut.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>mkdir "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14" 
AccŠs refus‚.

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>xxmklink "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\QGIS 2.14\OSGeo4W.lnk" "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\OSGeo4W.bat" " " \ "OSGeo for Windows command shell" 1 "C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads\OSGeo4W.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.


Failed to create the shortcut.
Running postinstall sip.bat...

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\Users\\viret-m\\Downloads 

C:\Users\viret-m\Downloads>textreplace -std -t apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sipconfig.py
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems you have installed QGis in your user-specific Download directory, and it is installed for all users. Since accessing your directory requires admin privs (or being you), the installation, which is done for all users, fails when creating the shortcut to your private directory.

==> uninstall QGIS and re-install in a an folder accessible by everybody, such as `C:\program files`, or don't install QGIS for every user but just for you.